# Why does the primefaces' paginator doesn't work after the application system keep online for about 2 days?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, paginator

The system's runtime environment is Mojarra jsf 2.0+primefaces 3.0+websphere7.0(tomcat6.0 is also has the problem).
The 2 days is not a exactly time. It's really means that the system keep running for a relatively long time, the paginator doesn't work. If the paginator told me there are 2 pages with the datatable, the first page can list the records of data.The second page show no record after click the paginator "2",but it should have several records indeed. 
 And I know the primefaces' paginator has relationship with session persistence.So I had checked the web server's free disk space, and it's thoroughly enough.
Can anybody give me some suggestions? I need your help.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the session timed out on your web application.  Your session persistence and any managed beans in session scope will end when this happens.

If your requirement is that the session never times out then I urge you to reconsider. Having a permanent session can be a security risk.

Comment: If a login user logs out, the session would be set timeout automatically.So the session is not permanent.Maybe there are some other reasons for this. But thanks all the same, it offered me a clue to resolve the problem.